# How to create a new Napa content add-in that runs on Powerpoint Online?

Tags: ms-office, office-addins, office-js

I want to make a new Napa content add-on, and I'm following this tutorial:

http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/get-started/create-an-office-add-in-with-napa

But then when I go to the page to select which Office application to run my content add-in, the "Launch your application in" selector is stuck on Microsoft Excel Web App. I cannot select any of the other options (nothing happens when I click on the other circles).

[image]

How can I run my content add-in on Microsoft Powerpoint Web App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Napa app doesn't even have the PowerPoint Web App listed.  You'll have to use Visual Studio to launch it.  I'm not sure if this is an oversight or a forthcoming feature that's not live yet.

Comment: So you mean that your Napa app only has Excel, Powerpoint, and Access, but not Powerpoint Web App?

Comment: Do you know of another way to develop a PowerPoint Web App? They obviously can be made because they are many on the App Store, but it is not clear to me how to develop them.

Comment: Yes, my Napa doesn't show the PowerPoint Web App.  I'm not sure why, but perhaps you are using a newer version of Napa (I have 1.3).  You can certainly continue to use Napa to develop your add-in, you just can't RUN it in PowerPoint from Napa.  You'll have to use Visual Studio to run and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Napa provides an excellent Getting Started experience but it isn't a full development environment. At some point you will likely need to export the Napa project and finish the add-in with Visual Studio.

If you do not have Visual Studio, you can use the free [Community Edition](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691978&clcid=0x409).